# Can't import the named export 'Children' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, framer-motion

im having this error when doing a named import from framer-motion module in reactjs.
Obs: im not using webpack.

```
import { Fragment } from "react";

import classes from "./Hero.module.css";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import Header from "../header/Header";

export default function Hero() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      <section className={classes.banner}>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1arVXy2.jpg" />
        <motion.h1 className={classes.slogan}>Produtos de alta performance</motion.h1>
        <div className={classes['see-more']}>
          <span>Veja mais</span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide more information and a way to reproduce your issue. Is that code the `index.mjs` file? Doesn't look like. Also, you should try to put the code inside code snippets, so that other users can copy it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: This is a bug in the new 5.x version. See this thread: https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1307

Comment: Not really sure why this got closed. I added the full response from Framer to this duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769360/error-importing-framer-motion-v5-in-react-with-create-react-app

Comment: I solved it by upgrading react-scripts.
https://github.com/doczjs/docz/issues/1686#issuecomment-999002953

Comment: Try This it worked for me Fixed this by changing >>>  import to " import {AnimatePresence, motion} from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion"; "

Comment: change the way to import motion, from import { motion } from 'framer-motion'; to import { motion} from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion";