# Images show same for all nested route page in react

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I get this error when i try to use framer motion in my project

```
./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Children' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

below is my import of motion from framer motion in my app component

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
```

then i tried using it

```
<motion.div>Animate div</motion.div>
```

and the moment i import motion from framer-motion, i get the above mentioned error..
But if i comment out the import line of code the error goes out and my code runs well again.. Please has anyone encountered this same issue...I need help

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Add your package.json to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Framer motion in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769360/framer-motion-in-react)

Comment: Thanks @Cadin you just saved me... It has worked now