importing framer-motion causes ReferenceError in React
I'm started to work with a React project which uses framer to animate elements in sidebar after login screen, but it is causing console error when importing: Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
I tested just by importing the library in login component, without using the library and is causing me the same behavior.
When import the lib like this:
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion";

The web site is just a blank screen, the console show this:
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
at framer-motion.js:1:1 at framer-motion.js:1:1
at ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/framer-motion.js (framer-motion.js:1:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/modules/auth/components/login-form/LoginForm.jsx (LoginForm.css:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1) at fn (bootstrap:150:1) at ./src/modules/auth/components/login/Login.jsx (LoginForm.jsx:125:1)
 at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1) at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/modules/auth/AuthModule.jsx (index.js:9:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1) at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/App.js (App.css:45:1) at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.css:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1) at 1 (useAuth.jsx:9:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
at main.chunk.js:1:69

In package.json i'm using versión 11.1.3
"framer-motion": "^11.1.3",
Tested with Chrome, Edge with same result

have yout tried import like this: import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion"?

Yes @SlavaSobolev forgot to mention that, importing that way i got this error: Failed to compile.
./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Children' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
Found that same issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769360/error-importing-framer-motion-v5-in-react-with-create-react-app) and suggest to import the way I mention. Thank you
